# Play Framework 2.x : Ajax request to controller without page refresh

Tags: ajax, playframework-2.3

I have a controller `LessonController` with an action `save()`. My route for this action is `POST /save     LessonController.save(name: String)`. The code is very simple for this action.

```
public static Result save(String name){
    Lesson lesson = new Lesson();
    lesson.setTitle(name);
    lesson.save();

    return ok(lesson.getLessonId().toString());
}
```

Here is my ajax call from the view

```
myJsRoutes.controllers.LessonController.save(name).ajax({
    success : function(id){
        alert('Success');
    }
});
```

This code does create a lesson but it refreshes the page and does not execute the success block from ajax request. I guess it is because I am returning a `Result` type back. I tried changing the return type to `String` but it gave me a compilation error.

So the question is, How can I call an action in a controller with ajax without the page refresh behaviour?

Comment: How do you make your Ajax call ? jQuery ?

Answer (score 0):

If you get a page refresh from that then it is for some other reason. Like for example triggering the ajax call with a submit button and not consuming the button event so that it leads to a form submit POST or GET

Answer (score 0):

Please check you AJAX call event, may but you are triggering the AJAX call using submit button or may be you are submitting any form in the web page with the same event.